# Use context manager as a function

Tags: python

I'd like to make a function which would also act as context manager if called with `with` statement. Example usage would be:

```
# Use as function    
set_active_language("en")

# Use as context manager
with set_active_language("en"):
    ...
```

This is very similar to how the standard function `open` is used.

Here's the solution I came up with:

```
active_language = None  # global variable to store active language

class set_active_language(object):

    def __init__(self, language):
        global active_language
        self.previous_language = active_language
        active_language = language

    def __enter__(self):
        pass

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        global active_language
        active_language = self.previous_language
```

This code is not thread-safe, but this is not related to the problem.

What I don't like about this solution is that class constructor pretends to be a simple function and is used only for its side effects.

Is there a better way to do this?

Note that I haven't tested this solution.

Update: the reason why I don't want to split function and context manager into separate entities is is naming. The function and the context manager do the same thing, basically, so it seems reasonable to use one name for both. Naming the context processor would be problematic if I wanted to keep it separate. What should it be? `active_language`? This name may (and will) collide with variable name. `override_active_language` might work, though.

Comment: You could try to use the `contextmanager` decorator from `contextlib` but then your function must be a generator, which I think is even less elegant. https://docs.python.org/2/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager

Comment: `open` holds state (the opened file handle) that is cleaned up when the object ref count goes to zero. `open('foo')` (without assigning it to anything) is only useful for its side effects. So, question... do you want `foo = set_active_language();del foo` to revert back to the original language? If so, the call is carrying state, just like `open`.

Comment: You are spending time trying to design/implement something of very questionable value. Think about it: do users *really* need it? Is that what makes your code useful? I doubt it. By 
the principle of least astonishment last thing I would expect for a class (not object!) to be a function AND context manager. Make function and context manager separate entities. Follow existing practices: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/translation/__init__.py#L170

Comment: I know it doesn't answer your question, but I agree with @Andrey that even if you figure out a way to do it, I don't recommend you do. If it's hard to do, it's probably the wrong way to do it. In this case, `set_active_language` would be the right name for the imperative. A context is rather declarative, for which I suggest you use `with active_language` or even `with language`.

Comment: This is what `open` does. Is `open` in Python an actual class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically no, you cannot do this.  But you can fake it well enough that people (who didn't overthink it) wouldn't notice.

```
def set_active_language(language):
    global active_language
    previous_language = active_language
    active_language = language

    class ActiveScope(object):
        def __enter__(self):
            pass

        def __exit__(self, *args):
            global active_language
            active_language = previous_language

    return ActiveScope()
```

When used as a function the `ActiveScope` class is just a slightly wasteful no-op.

Comment: You could make it slightly less expensive by declaring `ActiveScope` outside the function, and passing `language` as an argument to `__init__` instead of capturing it via a closure. Then you only have to pay the cost of instantiating `ActiveScope` instead defining the class every time you call `set_active_language`.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully someone will prove me wrong, but I think the answer is **no**: there is no other way. And also, another short-coming of the method you chose is that it might misbehave when used along with other context managers in a `with a, b, c:` statement. The intended side-effect of the CM is executed on object construction, and not in the `__enter__` method as would be expected.

To be able to do what you want, you would have to know from inside the class constructor whether it was initialized as a context manager in a `with` statement, or simply called as a function. As far as I can tell, there is no way to gather that, not even with the `inspect` module.